# Save page with Web Browser Control with JS and CSS files

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a `Web Browser Control` in windows application. I want to save page at specific folder with CSS files and JS files. I have used `webBrowser1.ShowSaveAsDialog()` method but by this user can save page at any location instead of my application folder.

So, how can I save pages with folder structure to my location without showing pop up menu?

Answer (score 0):

Good question!! all the browsers do it, iMacros ($495-$990) does it
Selenium, phantomjs, slimer, watir, etc CAN'T do it,

the closest i have seen to that sort of functionality is... 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2847/Automated-IE-SaveAs-MHTML
which uses c++ to hack the save as dialog.
You'd think that SaveAs webpage complete would be just another 
method on the browser control. But it doesn't seem so. I want
this functionality as well -- sorry this question remains unanswered.